# Indexes of elements

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have numpy array:
A = np.array([1,3,5,7,9])
and
B = np.array([3,3,3,5,5,5])

I want to have array C - which is index B in A.
C = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2])

How I can do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Please see ["How much research is expected of SO users?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) provides exactly the functionality you need.

```
C = np.searchsorted(A, B)
```